# Touch ID not working with Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm trying to do a quick test of the TouchId Ionic Native plugin.

Following along with the docs, I have the following setup in my controller:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TouchID } from '@ionic-native/touch-id';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private touchId:TouchID) {

  }
  this.touchId.isAvailable()
  .then(
    res => console.log('TouchID is available!'),
    err => console.error('TouchID is not available', err)
  );

this.touchId.verifyFingerprint('Scan your fingerprint please')
  .then(
    res => console.log('Ok', res),
    err => console.error('Error', err)
  );
}
```

But I'm getting a red squiggly line under the "This" in the line:       this.touchId.isAvailable(), which as we know highlights an error.

"[ts] Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected."

I've added the plugin and have it included in the provider section of the module.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have not wrapped your plugin calls inside a method. The question being 4 months old, I'm sure you've figured it out by now. Regardless, if anybody who's of Javascript background and is thrown off by Typescript class and method convention, I hope the answer helps. I'd also suggest wrapping any plugin calls with a platform.ready() call to make sure the plugin is properly initialized before being accessed.

```
export class AboutPage {

  constructor(platform: Platform, public navCtrl: NavController, private touchId:TouchID) {
    platform.ready().then(() => this.touchInit());
  }

touchInit() {
    this.touchId.isAvailable()
      .then((response: any) => {
          console.log('TouchID is available!', response);
          return this.touchId.verifyFingerprint('Scan your fingerprint please');
      })
      .then((res: any) => {
          console.log('Ok', res)
      })    
      .catch((error: any) => {
          console.error('Error', err)
      });
```

Comment: @SHUBHASISMAHATA: i'm sure the ionic native wrapper has changed since I answered more than 2 years ago. Please consult the docs for latest API usage.